# Do athasian druids follow the PHB druid XP progression and organization?

Tags: druid, adnd-2e, experience-points, dark-sun

Athasian druids have their guarded lands, and pretty much don't bother each other. So having a druidic organization like the one in the PHB seems not likely. Also, they don't seem to become hierophant.

But reading the Dark Sun setting, I could not find the druid XP progression. It seems to be using the one from the PHB.

What table the athasian druid uses for xp progression? Do they have a organization like archdruid, hierophant, great druid, etc (including the limit on leveling, dueling, etc)?

If they don't follow the PHB, what is the book that describes athasian druid progression?

Answer (score 3):

In the revised Dark Sun box, the "Age of Heroes" book:

Page 32:

> Unlike in other AD&D campaigns, there’s no worldwide organization of druids on Athas. As such, there are no rules limiting the number of druids that may exist at a given level, and there are no special druidic titles such as Archdruids and the Grand Druid. These don’t exist in a DARK SUN campaign.
>
> [...]
>
> ln all cases where the rules here don’t contradict them, the rules about druids in the *Player’s Handbook* should be used.

This means that:

1. There are no druidic organization, nor limits on how many druids at each level may exist.
2. They use the progression from the PHB
3. They have the same limitation on spellcasting (their progression halts on lv 15)
4. They become Hierophant.