# Does a priest of Erik receive ALL the powers of a druid?

Tags: adnd-2e, birthright

In Birthright's Rulebook, page 74, about Erik's priesthood is stated:

> PW as druid, plus move silently, hide in shadows, and animal empathy
> as a ranger three levels higher

Since in Birthright there is more than one church of Erik, and the head of the religion is a regent who can be a level 1 npc (or player), and at 15th level (from PH):

> The Grand Druid knows six spells of each level (instead of the normal
> spell progression) and also can cast up to six additional spell
> levels, either as a single spell or as several spells whose levels
> total to six (for example, one 6th-level spell, six 1st-level spells,
> three 2nd-level spells, etc.)

Or it is not considered a druid power, since derives from position, as his servants receive some too:

> Three of these nine are archdruids who roam the world, acting as his
> messengers and agents. Each of them receives four additional spell
> levels.

If so, hierophants powers are ignored too? Since their origin is from hierophant status and comes at cost of spells:

> Beyond 15th level, a druid never gains any new spells (ignore the
> Priest Spell Progression table from this point on). Casting level
> continues to rise with experience. Rather than spells, spell-like
> powers are acquired.

Answer (score 1):

In PHB we have a section named 'Granted Powers' in the description of druid class.  It lists powers until level 7 only.  The remaining powers are descripted in the hierarchy sections.

In the *Book of Priestcraft*, page 14, we have a hierarchical position not described in PHB: **high druid** (Thorjak, the Green is high druid of Hogunmark; Günther Brandt is high druid **and** regent of Oaken Grove of Erik; Gretta Seligsdotter is regent of Emerald Spiral; Astridsen is regent of Old Father of Forests).

This title seems not related to the regent position.

The Rjurik Highlands book, page 73, states that:

> Druids are loosely organized into groups known as circles, which may
>   include as few as three or as many as a dozen individuals. Circles are
>   generally led by high level blooded druids: if no blooded druids dwell
>   in the area, leadership is usually assumed by the highest level
>   member.

This book says that circles are allied with temples, but do not specify hierachies.

Taking in consideration both books, high druid appears to be just a honorific title, and classical (PHB) hierarchy inexistent.  It implies in a priest of Erik not fighting for positions at leveling, following the normal priest XP and spell progression tables and NOT receiving hierophant powers.

In my campaign I had decided to use **high druid** as regent (so, blooded characters only) and **great druid** as a diplomatic hierarchical post. The Great Druid was like the speaker-of-Erik and its only function was to moderate conflict between the churches, thus all druids existed exactly as PHB **except** the regent.

This view have its problems, like: what powers a high druid should have? And what powers his heir have? Can them become hierophant? Which XP progression to use? And if he passes his post to his heir? I see now that is better to go back to the 'just a priest' view.

It is different from [Dark Sun](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107106/do-athasian-druids-follow-the-phb-druid-xp-progression-and-organization) since in Birthright it is explicit  - a priest of Erik receive druid powers only.